# Navigating in WPF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am developing a WPF application, in which I am using different kind of menu bar...

`Home/Account/Profile"`

these are not more than labels,all I want is that ,when i click on a particular item in above navbar i should redirect to that page(like navigation bar in web).

I am not using `XAML` to do this and only working on purely c#

```
public class Breadcrumbs : StackPanel
{
    Label lab;
    public Breadcrumbs()
    {
        Width = 700;
        Height = 30;

        Background = Brushes.White;
        this.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    }
    static int i = 0;


    public void addBreadcrumbs(List<string>  newlist)
    {

        string[] newLabel = newlist.ToArray();
        for(int j=0;j<newLabel.Length;j++)
        {
        lab = new Label();
        lab.FontSize = 15;
            if (!(newLabel.Length - 1 == i))
            {
             lab.Content = newLabel[j] + "  /";
            }
            else
            {
                lab.Content = newLabel[j];

            }
            if (newLabel.Length - 1 == i)
            {
                lab.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(55,55,55));

            }
            else
            {
                lab.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(66,139,202));
            }
      this.Children.Add(lab);
      Console.WriteLine(lab.Content);
      i++;
        }//for loop end here
    }//addBreadcrums function end here
   }//class breadcrums end here
```

Comment: Why not XAML? WPF is not WinForms. You definitely should switch to data binding.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I am making my own custom control by making a class and using only those features which i required .. so i have to do all the stuff in code behind .

Comment: The idiomatic way to do this in WPF would be to define a custom style/template for an existing control or to implememnt attached behaviors. You should only define new controls if you want them to *behave* in a significantly different way than any existing control.

Comment: Yes!! and i know that..but since i am trying to make a completely new control...that's why i am making a new class ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is functionality for breadcrumb navigation built into WPF, no need to roll your own:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(v=vs.110).aspx